# Need to Center my CSS Menu

Tags: css, menu

I need help centering my CSS menu. Not sure why it isn't centered. I played around with the padding but it didn't change anything really. I know you just can't center it like you can with HTML though.

Here is the CSS:

Here is the page:

Thank you!
-Mike

Comment: I can see that you deleted the links to the code you had in the first version of the question. Do you want to remove the question as well, or are you going to add in some code so that the question can be answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding margin:auto in the css menu

```
#cssmenu {
    background: #000000;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    width: 595px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r3V95/)

Comment: it works on me. check the fiddle on the updated code.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry it did work. I put it in wrong as first... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think I did, I clicked the little green checkmark. Definitely coming here if I have any more problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add margin: 0 auto; to #CssMenu

```
#cssmenu {
position: relative;
height: 44px;
background: #000000;
width: 595px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 500;
  text-align: center; /*add this to center your li itens*/
  white-space: nowrap; /*add this if you dont want brake the 'HISTORY' link in another line*/

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block; /*you must remove float:left; and add change display to inline-block to display your li items side by side*/
  vertical-align: top; /*add this to make you li itens align by top*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```